# Regular expressions : How to make a conditional regex

Tags: c#, regex, match, conditional-statements

I have the following conditions for my regex :
When the string is not empty it should contain the word "internal"

So in other words :

```
"<link linktype='internal' id='{F88AE8AE-69C4-4E31-95BF-73B110FEE63A}' />" --> OK
"<link linktype='external' id='{F88AE8AE-69C4-4E31-95BF-73B110FEE63A}' />" --> NOK
"test" --> NOK
"" --> OK
```

I know that an empty string can be checked with : `^$`
Or a non empty string with : `^\s*\S`
and my internal check simply as : `linktype=\'internal\'` (for example)

Bringing them together is the hard part. I've been stuck on this, but it doesn't do as expected :

```
(?(?=^\s*\S)linktype=\"internal\"|^$)
```

Can anyone help ?

Comment: Does it need to be done with a regular expression?

Comment: Yes it is the only possible way in that software package

Comment: You are using C#. You could easily do as @Vache has suggested.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try `(^$)|(^.*linktype=\"internal\".*$)`

Either the empty string, or a string with the text `linktype="internal"`.

Comment: This might just be good enough for me, still i wonder how a conditional and expression should be done.

Comment: This is a conditional (the `|` is an "or") but also using capturing which requires the RE to do more work. You probably want a non-capturing group (i.e. starts with `(?:` instead of `(`) and you don't need the anchors in the second group if the string just must contain the "internal" check anywhere, like so: `(?:^$)|(?:linktype=\"internal\")`

Comment: Also, if the "linktype" may have double or single quotes so you must modify that again; second group: `(?:linktype=['\"]internal['\"])`.

Comment: @kris: if you want a conditional "and" expression (which is not what your question requires) in a RE you simply concatenate the two rules. Technically though the part that matches `linktype=['"]internal['"]` is an "and" expression of each literal rule and character set rule, that is: `l` and `i` and `n`, etc.

Answer (score 2):

Since you mentioned C#, you might as well try this:

```
if(str.Length == 0 || str.Contains("internal"))
```

It works and it's simple.

Comment: True and if no regex answer comes up i'll have to do smth like that by coupling it to my project but i'm guessing regex should be up to this.

Comment: Oh you can do it with a regex, but you have to ask yourself if you should. ;)

Comment: @Vache, I totally agree :-) As powerful as regexs can be, you also need to look at readability of your code. I can look at this answer and know exactly what it does, which isn't the case for the regex answers.

Answer (score 1):

In this particular case, you can use:

```
^(.*linktype=['"]internal['"].*)?$
```

Otherwise, it is easier to write a regex for each case separately and then enclose them in parenthesis and use a 'or' to include them in a single expression:

```
(^$)|(^.*linktype=['"]internal['"].*$)
```

This will match either `^$` or `^.*linktype=['"]internal['"].*$`.

Answer (score 0):

what about something like

```
(^$)|(^.*linktype=\"internal\".*$)
```

--Tomas

Answer (score 0):

something like this should do it:

```
^.*linktype='(internal|)'.*$
```

Answer (score 0):

```
"<link linktype='internal' id='{F88AE8AE-69C4-4E31-95BF-73B110FEE63A}' />" --> OK
"<link linktype='external' id='{F88AE8AE-69C4-4E31-95BF-73B110FEE63A}' />" --> NOK
"test" --> NOK
"" -->
```

If linktype='internal' is matched you don't really care of what is before and after the linktype='internal', you will anyway get a match:

```
(^$)|(linktype='internal')
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps I should add my own answer. The answers so far have used capturing groups which are slightly more costly. To use an "or" condition with a non-capturing group:

```
(?:^$)|(?:linktype=['\"]internal['\"])
```

There is no need for anchors on the second part as an RE by definition will match anywhere within the string without the anchors.

Also, to use an "and" condition in a RE you simply concatenate the rules together. This is how the above RE is formed actually. It is (anchor start AND anchor end) OR (an `l` AND `i` AND `n` ... AND character set ['"] AND `i` AND ... etc...)

Answer (score 0):

```
string regex = "^(?:\\n|.*linktype=([\'\"])internal\\1.*\\n)";
var options = RegexOptions.Multiline);
var reg = new Regex(regex, options);
```